# print dictionary keys and values in one column in tcl

Tags: tcl

I am new learner of tcl scripting language. I am using TCL version 8.5. I read text file through tcl script and count similar words frequency. I used for loop and dictionary to count similar words and their frequency but output of the program print like this: alpha 4 beta 2 gamma 1 delta 1
But I want to print it in one column each key, value pair of dictionary or we could say each key, value pair print line by line in output. Following is my script in tcl and its output at the end.

```
set f [open input.txt]
set text [read $f]
foreach word [split $text] {
    dict incr words $word
}
 puts $words
```

Output of the above script:
alpha 4 beta 2 gamma 1 delta 1

Comment: If you are new to Tcl, please consider using Tcl 8.6. It is as readily available as 8.5 and includes all the latest goodies. In addition to being actually supported.

Answer (score 1):

You would do:

```
dict for {key value} $words {
    puts "$key $value"
}
```

When reading [the `dict` documentation](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/dict.htm), take care about which subcommands require a *dictionaryVariable* (like `dict incr`) and which require a *dictionaryValue* (like `dict for`)

---

For nice formatting, as suggested by Donal, here's a very terse method:

```
set maxWid [tcl::mathfunc::max {*}[lmap w [dict keys $words] {string length $w}]]
dict for {word count} $words {puts [format "%-*s = %s" $maxWid $word $count]}
```

Or, look at the source code for the `parray` command for further inspiration:

```
parray tcl_platform  ;# to load the proc
info body parray
```

Comment: One might first iterate over the keys of the dictionary (`foreach key [dict keys $words] ...`) to determine the maximum width of the columns.